# C++ unique and set not working

Tags: c++, vector

unique is not working pls help
its showing compiler error

I tried making it a

```
set<str> se(ss.begin(), ss.end());
ss.assign(se.begin(), se.end());
```

I tried this too and it also shows compiler error

Is it because of the `bool sortByString()`

I saw that code in a page so that it helps to sort a vector class objects
if there is any other way pls help

```
#include <cmath>
#include<set>
#include <cstdio> 
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 
#include<string> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; 
int n;

class str
{
    public:
    string a;

    void in(string s)
    {
        a=s; 
    }

    string get(){
        return a;
    }

    void out()
    {
        cout<<a;
    }

};


bool sortByString(str &t1, str &t2)
{
    return t1.get() < t2.get();
}


string d(vector<str> a) 
{
    string s;


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        s.append(a[i].get());

    return s;
}



int main() {
    string s,sub; 
    cin >> s;
    int length = s.length();
    int i, k = 0, c;

    vector<str> ss;

    str a;
    n = length*((length + 1) / 2); 



    k = 0;



    for (c = 0; c < length; c++)
    {

        for (i =length-c;i>=1; i--)
        {


            a.in(s.substr(c,i));
            ss.push_back(a);

        }
    }

    s=" ";
    ss.erase(unique(ss.begin(),ss.end()),ss.end());  /*code giving compiler error pls help*/
      s=d(ss);
    cout<<s;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please add the compiler error verbatim in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `operator==` in str. [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) requires this operator.

```
class str
{
    //....
    bool operator==(const str& rop) const {
        return a == rop.a;
    }
};
```

Comment: could you pls tell me y

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> bool sortByString(str &t1, str &t2)
> ```

```
bool sortByString(const str &t1, const str &t2)
```

At least for g++. VS will compile any, as I think.